# Bottle running command after file download

Tags: python, file, export, bottle

I have a bottle "server" serving me block device images' in .raw format. Unfortunately, after download finishes (successfully or not, doesn't matter) I have to run one more method to unmount exported block device.

Below I provide the code which is used to export the image but only provides me with errors  (cannot unmap device as it's used by different process) and isn't exporting images as intended:

```
class ExportResponse(HTTPResponse):
    def __init__(self, devpath, volume_name):
        self.devpath = devpath
        self.volume_name = volume_name

        output_filename = "%s.raw" % (volume_name)

        fp = open(devpath)
        content_length = os.lseek(fp.fileno(), 0, os.SEEK_END)
        os.lseek(fp.fileno(), 0, os.SEEK_SET)
        headers = {
                'Content-Length': str(content_length),
                'Content-Type': "application/octet-stream",
                'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="%s"' % output_filename
                }
        log.info("%s, %s" % (os.SEEK_CUR, content_length))
        super(ExportResponse, self).__init__(fp, **headers)

@get('/retrieve/<volume_name>/')
def export_volume(volume_name):
    fmt = request.query['format']
    dev = find_mapping(volume_name)
    if dev:
        log.debug("export, name=%s, already mapped dev=%s" % (repr(volume_name), str(dev)))
    dev_owner = dev is None
    try:
        if not dev:
            map_volume(volume_name)
            dev = find_mapping(volume_name)
            log.debug("export, name=%s, mapped to dev=%s" % (repr(volume_name), str(dev)))
        return(ExportResponse(dev, volume_name))
    except:
        log.exception("export, name=%s" % repr(volume_name))
        if dev and dev_owner:
            unmap_volume(volume_name)
        raise
    finally:
        unmap_volume(volume_name)
```

Is there any good way of doing this?

Comment: `cannot unmap device as it's used by different process` -- why do you expect `unmap` to work if other processes are using it?

Comment: That's why I'm asking for help as I don't know how to finish exporting and then unmap device.

Comment: But you say it's being used by _a different process_.  So the problem has nothing to do with your own exporting, right?  Some other process all together is using the disk.

Comment: You don't understand.. This code works like this:
bottle starts to read the disk, but at the same time the device is being unmapped by "finally" set of instructoins. That's why I get "device is used by another process" error (device cannot be unmaped as the same app is trying to read from it)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this.

1) Read the entire image into memory using a [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) object.  Use that as the stream handle you pass to `__init__`, instead of the handle to the actual file.

2) Obtain from bottle the raw handle to the response stream and use the write() method on the stream to write chunks of the file yourself, closing it when you are done.  I am not sure how to get that stream from bottle, but I know it exists because the [WSGI protocol specifies the response is passed as a stream.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#id21)